# Eclipse + PyDev: use docstring for type checking (like PyCharm)

Tags: eclipse, pycharm, pydev, type-hinting, static-code-analysis

I'm very impressed for PyCharm capabilities to detect errors in my code by inspecting type hints in docstrings:

```
def f(a):
    """Some docs here

    :type a: int
    :rtype: str
    """
    ...
```

and I'm trying to replicate it in PyDev.

As described in [docs](https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html), PyDev can use docstring to infer parameters and return types:

So, I can ask PyDev for allowed methods (Ctrl + Space) based on variable type, but I can't use it for code checking, to make sure I don't misuse variables.

Is it possible to include this check during code analysis in PyDev?

Answer (score 1):

PyDev doesn't really do type checking for instances/parameters (even when it knows the type for code completion like in that case)... right now it only complains about tokens not found when following imports.

So, at this point, this would be a feature request for PyDev... I haven't implemented this so far because knowing the type can be tricky, but I think that when it's 100% sure of the type (from a type hint), it could really do that analysis -- it should be reasonably straightforward to implement too, so, the major issue is me having time to do it -- or having someone contribute it ;)

Comment: What about PEP-484 type hints?  Is there an open feature request for that?